# Manipulate values in different columns while doing an operation row by row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have some data containing hotel room booking information which looks like the sample below:

```
   user_id h_name h_capacity check_in_date check_out_date
         1     A1          2    2019-01-01     2019-01-05
         2     A1          2    2019-01-02     2019-01-05
         3     A1          2    2019-01-02     2019-01-03
         4     A2          3    2019-01-02     2019-01-04
         5     A2          3    2019-01-04     2019-01-05
```

`user_id`: id of the customer

`h_name`: Name of a hotel

`h_capacity`: Maximum number of rooms in the hotel.

`check_in_date` & `check_out_date` : self explanatory.

My aim is to find out which hotels are checking in people over their prescribed capacity.

The approach that I tried involves me creating new columns for each date that results in the sample dataframe given above. It would look like the following:

```
    <...> 2019-01-01 2019-01-02 2019-01-03 2019-01-04 2019-01-05
    <...>          0          0          0          0          0
    <...>          0          0          0          0          0
    <...>          0          0          0          0          0
    <...>          0          0          0          0          0
    <...>          0          0          0          0          0
```

`<...>` represents columns that are present in the first dataframe shown at the top.

After doing the above, I want to insert the number 1 into the columns of dates on which the user is living in the hotel.The result would look like this:

```
    <...> 2019-01-01 2019-01-02 2019-01-03 2019-01-04 2019-01-05
    <...>          1          1          1          1          1
    <...>          0          1          1          1          1
    <...>          0          1          1          0          0
    <...>          0          1          1          1          0
    <...>          0          0          0          1          1
```

`<...>` represents columns that are present in the sample shown at the top.

And in the end, I would just use summarize on h_name to get total beds occupied per day.

The problem is that I am unable to populate the dataframe as shown above with the value `1` in columns of dates where the person has occupied a room. **This involves populating a value into different columns for each row, which means that for a user, I would need to insert `1` into columns representing the dates that they stayed in a hotel.** I couldn't figure out an optimal solution for this and ended up using a `for` loop which took 32 minutes to execute.

I humbly request for an optimal solution for this. (Please note: Data has 500k rows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not following your approach, but this will solve your problem. Note: I assume the hotel capacity stay constant over time and the check out date is counted as a bed occupied as you did in your example.

```r
library(tidyverse)

hotel_data %>% 
  gather(check_in, date, check_in_date, check_out_date) %>% 
  group_by(h_name, h_capacity, user_id) %>% 
  complete(date = seq.Date(first(date), last(date), by = "day"), 
           fill = list(check_in = "stay")) %>% 
  group_by(h_name, date) %>% 
  mutate(people = n()) %>% 
  filter(people > h_capacity)

# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   h_name, date [2]
#   h_name h_capacity user_id date       check_in       people
#   <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl> <date>     <chr>           <int>
# 1 A1              2       1 2019-01-02 stay                3
# 2 A1              2       1 2019-01-03 stay                3
# 3 A1              2       2 2019-01-02 check_in_date       3
# 4 A1              2       2 2019-01-03 stay                3
# 5 A1              2       3 2019-01-02 check_in_date       3
# 6 A1              2       3 2019-01-03 check_out_date      3
```

**Explanation**
First I transform your data into the long format with `gather` as it is then easy to fill in the missing date values for each group (hotel and user) with `complete`. Then grouping only by the hotel and date I count the number of people and filter by those which exceed the capacity.

**Data**

```
hotel_data <- structure(list(user_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                             h_name = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2"), 
                             h_capacity = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 3), 
                             check_in_date = structure(c(17897, 17898, 17898, 17898, 17900), class = "Date"), 
                             check_out_date = structure(c(17901, 17901, 17899, 17900, 17901), class = "Date")), 
                        class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Hey Kath, Thanks for the elegant solution. Just had to make one change for it to work with my data: `date = seq(min(date), max(date), by = 1`